# Who is this female character near Aquaman, painted by Stjepan Sejic?

Tags: dc, comics, character-identification, aquaman

[Stjepan](http://nebezial.deviantart.com/) [Sejic](http://shiniez.deviantart.com/) has been [announced](http://www.dccomics.com/comics/aquaman-2016/aquaman-25) as the artist and writer for a number of upcoming issues of Aquaman, starting with *Aquaman* #25.

He's been posting some Aquaman arts lately, most recently this:

[image] [image]
<sub>Click for full resolution</sub>

People on Facebook haven't been able to identify her, and Sejic hasn't left a name.

Who is the character near Aquaman? I've never seen her being portrayed near him (not in recent DCAU films, neither in *Justice League Unlimited*).

Is she a recurring character, or something Stjepan Sejic has invented?

Comment: Mera after swimming in a bleached pool?

Comment: @KutuluMike No, Sejic would never give up her bushy red hair! :)

Comment: Aw, damn. He posted a comment - [she is Dolphin](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10154730106524125&set=a.10152664698559125.1073741834.742554124&type=3&comment_id=10154730127709125&comment_tracking=%7B"tn"%3A"R2"%7D). Hardly the most creative name DC has ever given :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The character in question appears to be [**Dolphin**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolphin_(comics)), a character originally introduced in 1968. She was "adopted" by the Atlanteans after rescuing Aquaman and his sidekick, but she was actually a human girl who had been given gills & webbed hands/feet through an alien experiment.

[image]

She was a romantic interest for Aquaman for a time while Mera was believed to be dead. When Mera returned, he broke off things with Dolphin and she ended up falling in love with his adopted son [Tempest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqualad) (formerly Aqualad) instead.

Needless to say, their family reunions from that time on were... awkward.

---

**UPDATE:** As asked by the OP in comments, confirmed that the webbed hands & feet have been part of the character since her very first appearance in 1968. Apparently artists are just inconsistent when it comes to showing those features on-panel.

[image]

Comment: recently [confirmed by the artist](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10154730106524125&set=a.10152664698559125.1073741834.742554124&type=3&comment_id=10154730127709125&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R2%22%7D), btw.

Comment: Aqua*lad*?! Ew. (@KutuluMike That was [embarassing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157127/who-is-this-female-character-near-aquaman-painted-by-stjepan-sejic#comment411738_157127) :P)

Comment: She doesn't appear to have the hand-fish-like things here - is that Sejic's invention?

Comment: @Gallifreyan - she's always had webbed feet, and I believe hands too. It wouldn't surprise me if various artists are just inconsistent in how they draw her. After all, webbed fingers generally aren't considered that attractive, and she's the Aquaman equivalent to Spider-man's Black Cat, so I'd imagine a lot of artists just leave that detail out.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I like that Sejic went with the webbing - finally an aquatic character who is at least remotely qualified to move underwater :)